# parabolic pde with source term

Tags: parabolic-pde

I was wondering if someone is aware of the application when pdes of the form arise
$$u_t+u_{xx}+g=0$$
i.e. there is a source term now. Any financial instruments that have this type of pde?

Comment: What is your source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}\left[h(B_T)+\int_t^Tg(B_s)ds|B_t=x\right]$$
where $B$ is a brownian motion.

So if you enter a contract whose underlying asset is $B$, such that you pay every day $t$, $-g(B_t)dt$ up to time $T$ where you receive $h(B_T)$, then the value of this contract is $u$

$$\partial_t u + \frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}u + g = 0$$ there is $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of $\partial_{xx}u$ same for my comment below.

Comment: Yes, but this in theory, are there contracts like that?

Comment: And if I use the discounted version of expectation, would both terms get multiplied by $e^{-r(T-t)} or only the terminal payoff?

Comment: it will be $h(B_T)e^{-r(T-t)}+\int_t^Te^{-r(s-t)}g(B_s)ds$, such that $\partial_t u + \partial_{xx}u + g -r u = 0$

Comment: many contracts like MTN are structured with a periodic payment up to maturity where you are paid the performance of some index

Comment: I see, thanks, and If I were to google, MTN stands for medium term notes in fixed income?

Comment: Also, something I am confused about: $u(t,x)$ is a conditional expectation and thus is a random variable. But on the other hand, when it is written in pde it is a function two dummy variables $t,x$ and has not randomness in it. so what is $u(t,x)$, random variable or real value function?

Comment: Conditional expectation thus random variable is not right. MJ73550's answer tells it all

Comment: @Quantuple: conditional expectation is a random variable written as $E[B(T)|B(t)]$, but I guess once you set $B(t)=x$ it becomes a number and not a random variable anymore, did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, exactly you are right

Comment: Assuming it exists $E(Z|X)$ is a measurable function of $X$. I.e : if it exists $h$ such that for any $f$ $E(Zf(X))=E(h(X)f(X))$ then $E(Z|X)=h(X)$.